# Does it make sense to define a class for Complex numbers, where real/imaginary parts use Numeric[T] instead of a concrete type?

Tags: scala, math, numbers, numeric, complex-numbers

Would something like

```
class Complex[T: Numeric](real: T, imag: T)
```

make sense, instead of writing a Complex class using `Double`s, one using `Long`s, one using `BigInt`s, so that everyone can choose the number type he needs?

How would performance compare to the non-generic approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the moment, `Numeric` is not `@specialized`. So the generic version using it will suffer from boxing and unboxing and the performances will be greatly reduced. Here is a nice blog post with performance measurments:

http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2011/06/scalas-numeric-type-class-pt-2/

However, you could directly write a `@specialized` version of your Complex number class without using `Numeric` and get all the benefits.

On a strictly pragmatic point of view, I am not sure to understand what's the usage of a complex number with integer parts...

Comment: I couldn't believe the complex integers are not useful and found this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.1389&rep=rep1&type=pdf The 'Gaussian integers' seem to be quite a nice representation for certain 2D graphics operations.